# spring security logout causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've been trying to understand spring-security for some time, and I've gotten around with most of the things except for the `logout` aspect. Going through other questions on SO, i felt most of them were facing problems related to the session not terminating.

I, on the other hand, am facing quite a different sort of trouble. My security XML file is configured as follows:

```
<http path-type="ant" auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
    access-denied-page="/?login_error=2">
    <intercept-url pattern="/web/open/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/web/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <form-login login-processing-url="/static/j_spring_security_check"
        default-target-url="/web/base/view" always-use-default-target="true"
        login-page="/" authentication-failure-url="/?login_error=1" />

    <logout logout-url="/static/j_spring_security_logout"
        invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" />
</http>
```

In my `web.xml` i've mapped the `login controller` to the context root [using the `welcome-file` list], and also have the required `springSecurityFilterChain` setup. Now the login operations run perfectly. The target JSP has a logout link as:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/static/j_spring_security_logout"/>">Logout</a>
```

However, whenever i click on the logout link, I get a ghastly `NullPointerException`. Can anyone let me know if there's some glaring mistake I'm making here?

---

Exception stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:334)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.getParameterValues(Parameters.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.getParameter(Parameters.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:384)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:140)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.determineTargetUrl(AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.handle(AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess(SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler.java:28)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
```

Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `determineTargetUrl` method in `AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler` seems to fail on getting request parameters. For me it's usually fine to provide a `defaultTargetUrl` and set `alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl` to `true` which meens that `determineTargetUrl` always returns the given URL and prevent URL determination magic.

I'd do this by registering my own `LogoutSuccessHandler` implementation like:

```
<logout
    logout-url="/static/j_spring_security_logout"
    invalidate-session="true"
    success-handler-ref="myLogoutSuccessHandler" />
```

instead of `logout-success-url`.

A `LogoutSuccessHandler` can look as simple as:

```
public class MyLogoutSuccessHandler extends AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication throws IOException, ServletException {
        // maybe do some other things ...
        super.handle(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

Set your logout URL as `defaultTargetUrl` in your security context when defining the bean for the custom `LogoutSuccessHandler`:

```
<bean id="myLogoutSuccessHandler" class="foobar.impl.MyLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" />
    <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: `extends AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler` can replaced by `extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler`.

Comment: gee - your advice did work, but it doesn't make any sense to me. none of the documentation mentions something like this. i fail to understand, why doesn't `logout` work without the `ref-handler`?

Comment: @Ischin: actually you don't need your own implementation at all. `<bean id="myLogoutSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler"> ... </bean>` is enough - but maybe you want to do some other things.

Comment: @anirvan: seems to be a **bug** in current version, see https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1803, https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1807

Comment: @jeha - man, just my luck to have begun my "education" of spring-security at such an auspicious time. +1'd for giving such a complete picture of the issue at hand.