# how to do logout in spring security

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-security, logout

I got the error when I click logout link in jsp. I am using spring security.

The exception is:

```
Jan 6, 2012 9:30:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/billingEngine] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.getParameterValues(Parameters.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.getParameter(Parameters.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:384)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:140)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.determineTargetUrl(AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.handle(AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess(SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler.java:28)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
```

The spring security .xml file is

```
<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"
    use-expressions="true">
    <custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <intercept-url access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" pattern="/common/admin/**" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/common/accounting/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/common/billing/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_COMPANY')" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login"/>
</http>
```

How to solve it out?

Thanks

Comment: Is your problem the same as this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325655/spring-security-logout-causes-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

It is a [bug SEC-1803](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1803), but it is fixed in Spring Security 3.0.7. So if you can update then update.